# Having a command send in am embed

Tags: discord.js

So I want to send a leaderboard command but in an embed but I cant seem to find out how to. This is all I could think of |

```
    const leaderboardEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Leaderboard')
            .setDescription('Top 10 leveled users are', message.channel.send(`**Leaderboard**:\n\n${lb.join("\n\n")}`))
    
            message.channel.send(leaderboardEmbed);
```

Comment: You can simply add a field to the embed containing the leaderboard contents. What you are *trying* to do in the above code is sending another message containing the leaderboard contents but not inside the embed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```js
const leaderboardEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Leaderboard')
            .setDescription('Top 10 leveled users are', 
            .addField({name:'1°:', value:'1° Username'},
              {name:'2°:', value:'2° Username'},
              {name:'3°:', value:'3° Username'},
              {name:'4°:', value:'4° Username'},
              {name:'5°:', value:'5° Username'},
              {name:'6°:', value:'6° Username'},
              {name:'7°:', value:'7° Username'},
              {name:'8°:', value:'8° Username'},
              {name:'9°:', value:'9° Username'},
              {name:'10°:', value:'10° Username'})
              
     message.channel.send(`**Leaderboard**:\n\n${lb.join("\n\n")}`))
    
            message.channel.send(leaderboardEmbed);
```

I know that's not the best way possible, but it's better that nothing!